# Mvc - Return file AND refresh page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, refresh, download

So in my action result, I return a file, which is downloaded.

```
return File(directory + @"\Issues.zip", "appicaltion/zip", "IssueReports.zip");
```

As well as that, I would like to refresh my page (This will get rid of some objects on the screen.
I would usually do that with

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

But I can't return two things at once, can I.
So if anybody could help out, that'd be great.

Thanks (:

Answer (score -1):

```
var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
zip.AddEntry("file1.txt", "content1");
zip.AddEntry("file2.txt", "content2");
zip.Save(outputStream);
}

outputStream.Position = 0;
return File(outputStream, "application/zip", "filename.zip");
```

Comment: Cannot create instance of ZipFile, son

Comment: And also, would that even refresh?

Comment: try zipping each file and return the newly zipped file to dwnload